# Replace NAs with previous day value for returns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, na

I would like to calculate the returns of an index and a share in the following dataframe. There are NAs in the index which I usually remove with `df <- na.locf(df)` . But I can't get it to work in my function. I would like the NAs to take the previous day value.

```
      Underlying       Date ClosingPrice MDAXClosing
1   DE0005089031 04.01.2016      49.5010    20256.14
2   DE0005089031 05.01.2016      49.7855    20228.06
3   DE0005089031 06.01.2016      49.0595    19989.88
4   DE0005089031 07.01.2016      47.7785    19537.39
5   DE0005089031 08.01.2016      47.7435    19321.93
6   DE0005089031 09.01.2016      47.8160          NA
7   DE0005089031 10.01.2016      47.7770          NA
8   DE0005089031 11.01.2016      48.8095    19219.43
9   DE0005089031 12.01.2016      48.9545    19627.76
10  DE0005089031 13.01.2016      48.0195    19587.69
11  DE0005089031 14.01.2016      47.1460    19296.48
12  DE0005089031 15.01.2016      43.5580    18789.76
13  DE0005089031 16.01.2016      43.4000          NA
14  DE0005089031 17.01.2016      43.4000          NA
15  DE0005089031 18.01.2016      44.4815    18662.69
16  DE0005089031 19.01.2016      45.6485    19029.23
17  DE0005089031 20.01.2016      44.8300    18322.99
```

To get my returns i use the following code

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format = "%d.%m.%Y")) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(week = cut.Date(Date, breaks = "1 week", labels = FALSE)) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Underlying, week) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(Stockreturn = log(ClosingPrice[1] / ClosingPrice[n()])) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(MDAXreturn = log(MDAXClosing[1] / MDAXClosing[n()]))
```

And this is how the output without MDAX looks like

```
   Underlying    week Stockreturn
   <fct>        <int>       <dbl>
 1 DE0005089031     1     0.0354 
 2 DE0005089031     2     0.117  
 3 DE0005089031     3    -0.0542 
 4 DE0005089031     4    -0.0162 
 5 DE0005089031     5     0.0622 
 6 DE0005089031     6    -0.0349 
 7 DE0005089031     7    -0.0303 
 8 DE0005089031     8    -0.00208
 9 DE0005089031     9     0.00361
10 DE0005089031    10    -0.0165
```

Here I would like to add my MDAXreturn in addition to the Stockreturn. Does anyone know how to add that to the code? I tried to add `dplyr::mutate(purchase = zoo::na.locf(MDAXClosing, na.rm = FALSE))`, but without results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace `NAs` with the previous values at the start of your pipe using `fill()` like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  fill(MDAXClosing) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format = "%d.%m.%Y"),
                week = cut.Date(Date, breaks = "1 week", labels = FALSE)) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Underlying, week) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(Stockreturn = log(ClosingPrice[1] / ClosingPrice[n()]),
                   MDAXreturn = log(MDAXClosing[1] / MDAXClosing[n()]))

# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   Underlying [1]
  Underlying    week Stockreturn MDAXreturn
  <chr>        <int>       <dbl>      <dbl>
1 DE0005089031     1     0.0354      0.0472
2 DE0005089031     2     0.117       0.0226
3 DE0005089031     3    -0.00780     0.0184
```

`MDAXreturn` can be calculated by calculating it in the same `summarise` statement as `Stockreturn`

**Data**

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
           ~Underlying,        ~Date, ~ClosingPrice, ~MDAXClosing,
        "DE0005089031", "04.01.2016",        49.501,     20256.14,
        "DE0005089031", "05.01.2016",       49.7855,     20228.06,
        "DE0005089031", "06.01.2016",       49.0595,     19989.88,
        "DE0005089031", "07.01.2016",       47.7785,     19537.39,
        "DE0005089031", "08.01.2016",       47.7435,     19321.93,
        "DE0005089031", "09.01.2016",        47.816,           NA,
        "DE0005089031", "10.01.2016",        47.777,           NA,
        "DE0005089031", "11.01.2016",       48.8095,     19219.43,
        "DE0005089031", "12.01.2016",       48.9545,     19627.76,
        "DE0005089031", "13.01.2016",       48.0195,     19587.69,
        "DE0005089031", "14.01.2016",        47.146,     19296.48,
        "DE0005089031", "15.01.2016",        43.558,     18789.76,
        "DE0005089031", "16.01.2016",          43.4,           NA,
        "DE0005089031", "17.01.2016",          43.4,           NA,
        "DE0005089031", "18.01.2016",       44.4815,     18662.69,
        "DE0005089031", "19.01.2016",       45.6485,     19029.23,
        "DE0005089031", "20.01.2016",         44.83,     18322.99
        )
```